# Using MicroserviceResponse as request body in POST method

Tags: microservices

I have used below as request body in my post method of Controller (@MicroserviceController).This Microservice is running as 2 instances in server (cloud based) to be used by consumer systems to update data.

```
@MicroserviceMethod
@RequestMapping(path = "/trial", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MicroserviceResponse doPost(final MicroserviceResponse msResponse) {

}
```

Is there a possibility that when the consumer of this api hits this REST API post call then the request body of one is used by  another api hit ? That is lets say consumer hits this api twice at exactly same time (upto milli second precision) and server processes at the same time. These are unique request body coming in msResponse, so will one will be used for another ?

Any guidance will help.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please describe the technology stack? What libraries and/or frameworks are used?

Comment: We are using Springboot,Java 1.8 and the microservice is deployed in PCF

Comment: I have issues finding any documentation on the MicroserviceMethod, MicroserviceRequest, and MicroserviceResponse classes mentioned in the code example. Could you please provide links? Or - better yet - provide a minimalistic example using classes from Spring Boot classes only.